2 Dimension $L^2$-zero counter-example.
Let $B\subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ centered at $(0,0)$ of radius $\delta < 1$. Suppose $g\in L^2(B)$ be continuous and only possess one zero; namely, $(0,0)$. Additionally, let $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I wish to either find such a $g(x,y)$ or prove that such a function does not exist with the properties that
$$
\frac{d}{g}\not\in L^2(B),
$$
but
$$
\frac{x}{g}\in L^2(B).
$$
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ Such a function easily exists if we remove the constraint that $g$ only has one zero. For example $g = x$ is such a function. Additionally, if $g$ had some sort of radial symmetry, no such function would exist due to the following computation. Suppose $g(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)) = u(r)v(\theta)$ such that $\text{ess inf} \,v(\theta) > 0$ and $u(r) = 0$ for $r = 0$. Then, by assumption we have that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|v(\theta)|^2}\,d\theta\int_0^{\delta}\frac{r^3}{|u(r)|^2}\,dr = \infty.
$$
Thus, as $v(\theta)$ is bounded below, $\frac{1}{v(\theta)}$ is bounded above. Hence,
$$
\int_0^{\delta}\frac{r^3}{|u(r)|^2}\,dr = \infty.
$$
Moreover, when converting $\frac{x}{g}$ into polar coordinates and integrating, we obtain that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{|v(\theta)|^2}\,d\theta\int_0^{\delta}\frac{r^3}{|u(r)|^2}\,dr,
$$
By as $\cos{\theta}$ is bounded we have that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{|v(\theta)|^2}\,d\theta < \infty.
$$
Hence, we must also have that $\frac{x}{g} \not\in L^2(B)$.
My issue is showing that no such $g$ exists. Any advice or counter-example would be appreciated.

$L^{2}(B)$ functions are only defined almost everywhere, so having only one zero does not have any meaning. Do you want to assume continuity of $g$?

@geetha290krm I was just thinking about that last night. I think assuming continuity is necessary.
